# How can I make SSI's work on my PC in my browser using Apache (& developing in Dreamweaver)?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, include, dreamweaver, ssi

I am designing a website in Dreamweaver. I want to use SSI’s (in order to not have redundant HTML code). I need to be able to test all my pages (including the SSI’s, the many links, and much more) on my own computer in my own browser.

** On my Windows 7 Professional operating system, I am successfully “Running all Apache services”.

** My file with my #include directive has an extension of .shtml.

** My .HTACCESS file is in the same folder as the .shtml file (and the included file).

Yet the SSI “include” part is not working in any of my browsers (e.g., Firefox, IE, Chrome, Safari). The SSI included code ***does*** show up fine within Dreamweaver.

It’s my understanding that I don’t need SQL or PhP for this part. Correct?

I’ve found 2 different sets of code, said to be needed inside the .HTACCESS file. I’ve tried both sets separately, but neither makes a difference. They are here:

```
AddType text/html .shtml
AddHandler server-parsed .shtml
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes
```

and here:

```
Options +Includes
AddType text/html .shtml
AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml
```

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/dreamweaver/cs/using/WSc78c5058ca073340dcda9110b1f693f21-7b6ba.html says:

> There are two types of server-side includes: Virtual and File... If
>   your server is an Apache web server, select Virtual. In Apache,
>   Virtual works in all cases...

I’ve tried both “Virtual” and “File”, but neither makes a difference.

I’m used to HTML and CSS, but I’m new to Dreamweaver, SSI, Apache, and files such as .HTACCESS. I’ve read a lot of help around the internet but cannot find what I’m doing wrong. Thanks, if you have a suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up achieving my goals in PHP instead. I don't have advice on the SSI's, since I could never make that work. But PHP includes are easy once you get PHP set up.